# How to prove a mapping from R to a subspace of a quotient space is continuous

Tags: general-topology

I define an equivalence relation : $$\begin{align*}
x \sim y \iff x = y + 2n\pi : n \in   \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}$$ Then by this relation, the quotient space is denoted as $\ ^{\mathbb{R}}\!/\!_{2 \pi \mathbb{Z}}$, and there exists a quotient map $$\begin{align*}
\pi: &\mathbb{R} \to \ ^{ \mathbb{R}}\!/\!_{2\pi \mathbb{Z}}
\\ & x \to [x]
\end{align*}$$
Consider $$\begin{align*}
U= \left\{ [x ] : x \in   (-\pi , \pi)\right\}
\end{align*}$$ I define a map $$\begin{align*}
\phi: &U \to \mathbb{R}
\\ &[x ] \to \tan \frac{x}{2}
\end{align*}$$ I want to check that $\phi$ is a homeomorphism.
By the $\pi$ period of $\tan$, $\phi$ is well-defined and it's easy to check that $\phi$ is 1-1 and onto.
$\phi$ is continuous since $$\begin{align*}
 \phi \circ \pi: x\to \tan \frac{x}{2}
\end{align*}$$ is continuous.

I would like to check $$\begin{align*}
\phi^{-1} :& \mathbb{R} \to U 
\\ &y \to [ 2\arctan y]
\end{align*}$$ is also a continuous map. Equivalently, I tried to show $\phi$ is an open mapping, but, I got stuck here.

Any help on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, $\Bbb R/2\pi\Bbb Z$ is the circle $S^1$ and your $U$ is just $S^1$ minus the north pole, the long open arc, and your map $\phi$ is basically a stereographic projection that identifies $\Bbb R$ with this open subarc of $S^1$ (more accurately, a map that identifies $S^1$ as the one point compactification of $\Bbb R$).

I'm going to go through this explicitly. There are some more high level ways to check $\phi$ is a homeomorphism that I'll mention later.

---

What are the open sets of $U$? Well, firstly we should ask what the open sets of $\Bbb R/2\pi\Bbb Z$ are; they are the sets $[V]$ where $V$ is open **and saturated** in $\Bbb R$, meaning if $x\in V$ and $y\sim x$ then $y\in V$. Therefore open subsets of $U\subset\Bbb R/2\pi\Bbb Z$ are intersections $[V]\cap U$ where $V$ is as above.

Let $[V]\cap U$ be such an open set. Since $V$ is a saturated open, it is in particular open. Because we know $\arctan$ is continuous, the preimage $W:=(2\arctan)^{-1}(V\cap(-\pi,\pi))$ is open in $\Bbb R$.

What we now want to do is claim $W=\phi([V]\cap U)$; then we would be done as we will have shown $\phi$ is an open map. Let $w\in W$. We know $\tan(w/2)\in V\cap(-\pi,\pi)$. It is then clear $\tan(w/2)=\phi([w])$ and that $[w]\in[V]\cap U$, since $[w]\in U$ by definition of $U$ and $[w]\in[V]$ simply because $w\in V$. Therefore $W\subseteq\phi([V]\cap U)$.

To see the reverse inclusion, let $y\in\phi([V]\cap U)$. That means there is $[x]\in[V]\cap U$ such that $\tan(x/2)=y$. $[x]\in[V]$ means there exists $x'\in V$ such that $[x]=[x']$ i.e. $x\sim x'$; **as $V$ is saturated**, that implies $x\in V$ as well (this is crucial!) and $[x]\in U$ means there is $x''\in(-\pi,\pi)$ such that $x\sim x''$; *again* as $V$ is saturated, this means $x''\in V$. To recap, we know there is some point $x''\in V\cap(-\pi,\pi)$ with $x\sim x''$. Therefore $y=\tan(x/2)=\phi([x])=\phi([x''])=\tan(x''/2)$ and $2\arctan(y)=x''$ where $x''\in V\cap(-\pi,\pi)$, so $y\in W$ by definition of $W$; therefore $\phi([V]\cap U)\subseteq W$ as desired.

---

To see this in some other ways, we could just directly prove $\Bbb R/2\pi\Bbb Z$ is the one-point compactification of $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ and that $U$ corresponds to $(\Bbb R\cup\{\infty\})\setminus\{\infty\}=\Bbb R$ under this homeomorphism. Alternatively, we could use universal properties of the quotient. Firstly as $U=[V_0]$ for $V_0=\bigsqcup_{n\in\Bbb Z}((2n-1)\pi,(2n+1)\pi)$ an open *saturated* set, we see the quotient map $q:\Bbb R\twoheadrightarrow\Bbb R/2\pi\Bbb Z$ restricts to a map $q|_{V_0}:V_0\twoheadrightarrow U$ **and this is also a quotient map**. To say $U\cong\Bbb R$ is then to say (by the universal property) that there is a quotient map $V_0\twoheadrightarrow\Bbb R$ inducing the same relation on $V_0$; $\tan((-)/2)$ defines a map $V_0\to\Bbb R$ and by continuity of $\arctan$ you actually know this map is open - and it is also a continuous surjection - so you know that it is a quotient map for free (!) and moreover it induces the correct quotient relation, so you're done.